# Appveyor PR bulid runs master branch

Tags: appveyor

I have a [GitHub PR](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json/pull/235) that merges into master.  It's built by Appveyor using [this configuration file](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/blob/master/appveyor.yml).

I have it configured to run documentation build and deploy only on master.  The "branch" build runs fine, but it looks like the "pr" build is trying to run on master.  (I understand that the "pr" build is building the anticipated merge result.)

How can I get it to run the documentation stuff only when it's actually building master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... I have the docs build under the `on_success` block, whereas I really want to do it under the `after_deploy` block.

`on_success` runs after every successful build, but Appveyor is smart enough to not run the deploy components on a "pr" build.  It therefore doesn't run the `after_deploy` on that build.